# Регулярное выражение для фильтрации городов

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

у меня есть большой список городов, мне нужно его отфильтровать так, чтобы в нем не было городов, в названии которых присутствуют не латинские символы. Но при этом города содержащие пробельные символы оставались в списке.
Я делаю так:

```
list.filter(({ cityName }) => !/\W/i.test(cityName));
```

Но такой фильтр отсеивает города, содержащие пробельные символы, например Los Angeles, как можно обойти это?

Comment: Тогда используйте `/[^\w\s]/`,  если нужно из `/\W/` "вычесть" пробельные символы.

Comment: может тогда так `/^[\w\s]+$/`?

Comment: Wiktor, cпасибо, работает.
Денис, ваше выражение фильтрует больше, чем нужно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно из /\W/ "вычесть" пробельные символы, используйте

```
/[^\w\s]/
/(?!\s)\W/
```

И `[^\w\s]`, и `(?!\s)\W` означают одно и то же: найди символ, отличный от пробельного и "словного" (цифро-буквенного, а также символа подчёркивания) символа.

См. [пример работы выражения №1](https://regex101.com/r/oPZlTG/1) и [выражения №2](https://regex101.com/r/oPZlTG/2).

Comment: А как можно изменить ваши выражения так, чтобы они еще и цифры искали?

Comment: @EgorG `/(?!\s)[\W\d]/` или `/[^\w\s]|\d/`